# How can I assign a value to self inside a block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, self

I'm trying to refresh my class entity with data from server. So I need to assign a value to self inside a success block. When I use __weak before block reference to self, I've got nil in self after assignment. And without __weak I've got a retain cycle. So is it possible to assign a new value to self inside a block? If it's not, are there any other ways to refresh a self value?

```
- (void) refreshAssignment:(void (^)())successBlock  Error:(void (^)(NSString *errorMessage))errorBlock{
NSString *subUrl = @"/getAssignmentById";
NSDictionary *prs = @{@"assignmentId":self.taskId,
                      @"mask":[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]
                      };
__block __weak Assignment* Self = self;
[[NetworkManager sharedSource] getStandart:prs andUrl:subUrl Success:^(NSDictionary *data) {
    Self = [[NetworkManager sharedSource] assignmentsWithArray:data[@"data"] Type:Self.type][0];
} Error:^(NSString *errorMessage) {
    errorBlock(errorMessage);
}]; }
```

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. You make a new variable called `Self`, that is initialized to `self` but you later assign something else to it in a block, but `Self` is not used by anything after that assignment, so it is unclear what the point of the assignment is.

Answer (score 0):

The correct `weakSelf` pattern is:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
```

But you can't assign anything to `self`.

The only place where the assignment to `self` is possible is in the `init` method.

Probably you want to assign the results to a property in the class.

Comment: So if I call my method init, how  can I assign a value to self inside  a block? __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self; - this is a const link to self. It's gonna be impossible to assign to weakSelf anything.

Comment: You cannot assign any value to self. `self` is a pointer to the object. So inside the block, you can modify properties of the object but not the object itself. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to refresh self object with data from server

Comment: my suggestion is that you refresh properties inside the object.